# Поиск по Firebase с критериями

Tags: java, android, база-данных, firebase

Моя база данных в RealTime Database Firebase имеет следующую структуру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**JSON**

```
{
  "Recepts" : [ {
    "Ingridients" : [ "Sugar", "Carrot", "Orange" ],
    "Name" : "Carrot Salad"
  }, {
    "Ingridients" : [ "Orange", "Milk" ],
    "Name" : "Orange Milk"
  } ]
}
```

В своем андроид приложении я хочу добиться следующего результата:

При выборе нескольких рецептов выполняется поиск по моей бд совпадающих 
рецептов.

Приведу пример:

Пользователь выбрал `Sugar` и `Orange` в результате выполнения запроса он должен получить `Carrot Salad`
Я использую Java.
Как я могу реализовать это в своей программе?

**upd**

Я написал такой код:

```
rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); //Общая ссылка на бд
DatabaseReference resultRef = rootRef.child("Recepts");
Query resultQuery = resultRef.orderByChild("Ingridients"); //Работаем с поиском рецептов
resultQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            //Здесь будет вложенный цикл для сравнения
            String comp = ",";
            String[] selected = selectedItems.split(comp);
            for(int i = 0;i<selected.length;i++){
                if (selected[i].contains(ds.child("Ingridients").getValue(String.class))) {
                    result_list.add(ds.getValue(String.class));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Здесь `selectedItems` - это объект класса `String` в котором содержатся выбранные элементы из `ListView` в цикле я сравниваю каждый выбранный элемент с полями `Ingridients` каждого рецепта в моей базе данных.
Но я столкнулся с проблемой:

Судя по логам я получаю такую ошибку

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Насколько я понимаю это происходит из-за того что этот код выполняется в тот момент, когда пользователь еще ничего не выбрал в `ListView` поэтому массив пуст и `=null`. Отсюда еще 1 вопрос, как выполнить этот код, после того как пользователь что то отметил в  `ListView`?

Comment: То, что вам точно не нужно делать - это обрабатывать запросы к БД в Java-коде своего приложения. БД должна отдавать готовые данные, которые не нужно дополнительно копошить и что то там высеивать из них. Сам я с Firebase не работал, поэтому ответ писать не буду, но как я понял, для выборки по нескольким условиям вам нужно просто указать несколько методов выборки, как например:`Query resultQuery = resultRef.orderBy("Ingridients").equalTo("Sugar").equalTo("Orange");` / Так же смотрите [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26701282/7566397) может он вам поможет.

Comment: @pavlofff К сожалению вариант который вы предложили по ссылке не может мне помочь, т.к. в том примере разработчик знает к какому полю обращаться(В том посте этими полями являются `genre` и `lead`) когда у меня в базе данных у рецепта может быть сколько угодно ингредиентов и они представленны в виде массива(`0`-`Sugar`,`1`-`Carrot` и т.д.)